# What is the Error in this code1?

Tags: c

I correct all Errors ,but the compile find one Error , I cant find it

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <conio.h>
  int main(void)

{

    float side,base,heigh;
    char a;
    printf("S-square\nT-traingle");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if(a=='S'||a=='s')
    {

        printf("enter the value of side");
        scanf("%f",&side);
        printf("area=%f",side*side);
    }

    else if(a=='t'||a=='T')
    printf("enter the base,heigh");
    scanf("%f%f",&base,&heigh);
    printf("area=%f",0.5*heigh*base);

    else  
    printf("not valid choise");

}
```

this code about find the area of traingle and squre using "if" loop
but i cant find where is the Error

Comment: Well what does the error say?

Comment: why is this tagged c++?

Comment: You are absolutely expected to be able to resolve trivial compiler errors...

Comment: am sorry this is the first time @EdHeal

Comment: 'else' without a previous 'if' @sftrabbit

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Answer (score 2):

You missed braces `{}` of `else`

```
 else if(a=='t'||a=='T')
{
     printf("enter the base,heigh");
     scanf("%f%f",&base,&heigh);
     printf("area=%f",0.5*heigh*base);
}
```

without braces the compiler treat this snippet as

```
else if(a=='t'||a=='T')
{
     printf("enter the base,heigh");
}
scanf("%f%f",&base,&heigh);
printf("area=%f",0.5*heigh*base);
```

and the next `else` cause error as it has no previous `if`(an `else` must have its previous `if`).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing braces around the different parts of your `if` statement:

```
else if(a=='t'||a=='T') {
    printf("enter the base,heigh");
    scanf("%f%f",&base,&heigh);
    printf("area=%f",0.5*heigh*base);
} else {
    printf("not valid choise");
}
```

While the last pair of braces isn't actually necessary, it's considered good practise to always use them to avoid problems like the one you were having.